# NuGet with TeamCity for project shared by 2 solutions - .h file not found

Tags: c++, teamcity, nuget, nuget-package-restore, casablanca

**The environment before NuGet (simplified):**

- One project shared by 2 solutions (sol1 and sol2).
- both solutions are successfully build by TeamCity.

**Adding NuGet**

- In sol1 I added a package to the project (Casablanca's C++ REST API).
- In one of the .c file in the project I added `#include <cpprest/json.h>`.
- In both solutions if have enabled `NuGet package restoration`.

**Result**

- Locally both solutions are still successfully build.
- Sol1 is build successfully on the TeamCity as well.
- Sol2 failed to build on the TeamCity given an error that the `cpprest/json.h file can't be found` when trying to compile the .c file.
- Note: during the build of sol2 on the TeamCity I see that the package is successfully downloaded and installed.

What can cause Sol2 to be unable to find the included json.h file?

Comment: At a guess it might be the Sol2 file is sitting in a different relative location to the Sol1 file with respect to the project.  Where does the project file expect the cpprest/json.h file to be?

Comment: My point being that NuGet by default creates the nuget package install dir in the solution file directory

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cpprest/json.h>
```

probably has to be something like

```
<../packages/casablancaapi/native/lib/cpprest/json.h>
```

Comment: I asked it more than a year ago and we end up dropping NuGet all together. So I will just trust you it works (: